# How can I avoid 401 responses going to the Failed Request group on AppInsight for my website

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

Currently all the unauthorized responses (401) are going to the Failed Request metric on Application Insights (as per the definition all responses with status code > 400 will go here). This scenario is making end user confused.

Any ways to avoid it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can write telemetry initializer that changes success property of the autogenerated request.

```
public class RequestStatusCodeTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var request = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (request != null && request.ResponseCode == "401")
        {
            request.Success = true;
        }
    }
}
```

More on custom telemetry initializers [here](http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/).